# Convert from long wide data fromat to long data format in R with multiple depth headers

Tags: r, reshape2, import-from-excel, melt

Maybe this can't even be done because I have my data in a bad format, but I'm trying to get it from a "kind of" wide format to a long format.  If I modify the data in excel first, I know how to do this with melt, but I have a LOT of data, and I'm hoping to not have to modify it all by hand first.

Basically I have my headers have depth where I have multiple descriptors for each column of sales.  Account, Brand, Variety and Tier (and maybe some others as well depending on how this goes)

```
            Account
            Brand
            Variety
            Tier
Dates   
1/1/2011    Sales xxx
2/1/2011    Sales xxx
```

And the format I need it in would be

```
Date Account Brand Variety Tier Sales
```

I don't understand how to convert this using reshape or melt though.  Any suggestions, or do I just have to do it by hand?

EDIT

Actual data looks something like this  (names changed to protect the innocent)

```
Account   Account A Account A   Account A   Account A   Account B
Brand     Brand A   Brand A         Brand B         Brand B         Brand C
Variety   Cab           Chard           Merlot          Pinot Grigio    Pinot Noir
 Tier     Tier 2    Tier 3          Tier 2          Tier 1          Tier 3
Date                    
6/1/20     35            47              35               28               -   
7/1/2011   12            17              12               12              84               
8/1/2011   -             -               -                -                -   
9/1/2011   7             7           7            7               84 
10/1/2011 28             28              28              28              112 
11/1/2011                                            168 
12/1/2011  7             7           7            7              224 
1/1/2012                 14                              236
```

If I massage it in excel to look like this

```
    Date    Compilation_Red Compilation_White   Oak_Cab Oak_Chard
1   11/1/2012   351 140 183 190
2   12/1/2012   191 99  120 92
3   1/1/2013    96  56  87  51
4   2/1/2013    30  30  84  61
5   3/1/2013    96  70  100 57
6   4/1/2013    60  38  52  22
7   5/1/2013    12  17  65  49
8   6/1/2013    9   7   28  21
9   7/1/2013    16  13  23  22
10  8/1/2013    26  29  40  33
11  9/1/2013    14  4   30  23
12  10/1/2013   17  4   47  31
13  11/1/2013   23  5   63  35
14  12/1/2013   25  3   70  41
15  1/1/2014    44  1   88  41
16  2/1/2014    28  7   57  43
```

Then I know how to use melt to get it into long format

```
myItem=melt(Account, id.vars="Date", variable.name="Variety", value.name="Sales")
```

I just don't understand how to deal with all the extra headers, and get them into the long format.

Also, I don't understand why my table looks fine when I put it in, but is mashed together in the preview.

Comment: You'll get much more help if you [make your question reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), at the very least post some actual data

Comment: Please post a better sample of the data and exact result you're looking for.  Also, please show us the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Use dput() to let us try the code ourself.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this way will help you.

```
devtools::install_github("yikeshu0611/onetree")
```

`onetree` is my own package in github. There is a function: `reshape_toLong`, which is used to transform wide data to long format.

```
library(onetree)
```

Your problem happened at the title, however, from your data posed above, it is difficult to identify the title.
If you have a long title like this

```
wide=read_Text("
AccountBrandVarietyTierDate AccountABrandACabTier2 AccountABrandAChardTier3   AccountABrandBMerlotTier2   AccountABrandBPinotGrigioTier1   AccountBBrandCPinotNoirTier3
6/1/20     35            47              35               28               -   
7/1/2011   12            17              12               12              84               
8/1/2011   -             -               -                -                -   
9/1/2011   7             7               7                7               84 
10/1/2011  28            28              28               28              112 
11/1/2011  -             -               -               168                -
12/1/2011  7             7                7               7              224 
1/1/2012   -             14              -              236               -")


colnames(wide)[1]="date" #change the id var to be different

long = reshape_toLong(data = wide,
                       id = "date",
                        j = "newcolumn",
          value.var.prefix = "Account")

head(long,10)

        date         newcolumn Account
1     6/1/20   ABrandACabTier2      35
2   7/1/2011   ABrandACabTier2      12
3   8/1/2011   ABrandACabTier2       -
4   9/1/2011   ABrandACabTier2       7
5  10/1/2011   ABrandACabTier2      28
6  11/1/2011   ABrandACabTier2       -
7  12/1/2011   ABrandACabTier2       7
8   1/1/2012   ABrandACabTier2       -
9     6/1/20 ABrandAChardTier3      47
10  7/1/2011 ABrandAChardTier3      17
```

Then we use Left, Right, Mid and Reverse function to deal with newcolumn column.

```
long$AccountABC = Left(long$newcolumn,1)
long$Brand = Mid(long$newcolumn,2,6)
long$Tier=Right(long$newcolumn,5)
Variety1= Mid(long$newcolumn,8,60)
Variety2=Mid(Reverse(Variety1),6,60)
long$Variety=Reverse(Variety2)
head(long,20)
        date          newcolumn Account AccountABC  Brand  Tier Variety
1     6/1/20    ABrandACabTier2      35          A BrandA Tier2     Cab
2   7/1/2011    ABrandACabTier2      12          A BrandA Tier2     Cab
3   8/1/2011    ABrandACabTier2       -          A BrandA Tier2     Cab
4   9/1/2011    ABrandACabTier2       7          A BrandA Tier2     Cab
5  10/1/2011    ABrandACabTier2      28          A BrandA Tier2     Cab
6  11/1/2011    ABrandACabTier2       -          A BrandA Tier2     Cab
7  12/1/2011    ABrandACabTier2       7          A BrandA Tier2     Cab
8   1/1/2012    ABrandACabTier2       -          A BrandA Tier2     Cab
9     6/1/20  ABrandAChardTier3      47          A BrandA Tier3   Chard
10  7/1/2011  ABrandAChardTier3      17          A BrandA Tier3   Chard
11  8/1/2011  ABrandAChardTier3       -          A BrandA Tier3   Chard
12  9/1/2011  ABrandAChardTier3       7          A BrandA Tier3   Chard
13 10/1/2011  ABrandAChardTier3      28          A BrandA Tier3   Chard
14 11/1/2011  ABrandAChardTier3       -          A BrandA Tier3   Chard
15 12/1/2011  ABrandAChardTier3       7          A BrandA Tier3   Chard
16  1/1/2012  ABrandAChardTier3      14          A BrandA Tier3   Chard
17    6/1/20 ABrandBMerlotTier2      35          A BrandB Tier2  Merlot
18  7/1/2011 ABrandBMerlotTier2      12          A BrandB Tier2  Merlot
19  8/1/2011 ABrandBMerlotTier2       -          A BrandB Tier2  Merlot
20  9/1/2011 ABrandBMerlotTier2       7          A BrandB Tier2  Merlot
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is like this, it is more easy.

```
wide=read.table(header = FALSE, text = ("
Account   AccountA AccountA   AccountA   AccountA       AccountB
Brand     BrandA   BrandA     BrandB     BrandB         BrandC
Variety   Cab      Chard      Merlot     PinotGrigio    PinotNoir
Tier      Tier2   Tier3     Tier2        Tier1           Tier3
6/1/20     35      47          35        28               -   
7/1/2011   12      17          12        12              84               
8/1/2011   -       -           -         -                -   
9/1/2011   7       7           7         7               84 
10/1/2011  28      28          28        28              112 
11/1/2011  -       -           -         168              -
12/1/2011  7       7           7         7               224 
1/1/2012   -       14          -         236              -
          "))
```

we can change row1 to row4 as one string and treated as column names.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(wide)) {
  colnames(wide)[i]=inner_Add_Symbol(wide[1:4,i],"_")
}
```

Then we delet from row1 to row4, and change column names 1 as date, which will be treated as id.

```
wide2=wide[-(1:4),]
colnames(wide2)[1]="date"
```

**key step** reshape to long data

```
long=reshape_toLong(data = wide2,
                      id="date",
                      j="newcolumn",
    value.var.prefix = "Account")
```

split the column in this dataframe

```
head(split_byonecolumn(long,"newcolumn","_",c("AccountABC","Brand","Variety","Tier")))

       date          newcolumn Account AccountABC  Brand Variety  Tier
1    6/1/20 A_BrandA_Cab_Tier2      35          A BrandA     Cab Tier2
2  7/1/2011 A_BrandA_Cab_Tier2      12          A BrandA     Cab Tier2
3  8/1/2011 A_BrandA_Cab_Tier2       -          A BrandA     Cab Tier2
4  9/1/2011 A_BrandA_Cab_Tier2       7          A BrandA     Cab Tier2
5 10/1/2011 A_BrandA_Cab_Tier2      28          A BrandA     Cab Tier2
6 11/1/2011 A_BrandA_Cab_Tier2       -          A BrandA     Cab Tier2
```